# Cordova/PhoneGap disable overlay/popup of speech recognizer

Tags: android, cordova, popup, speech-recognition

I am creating a simple WebApplication using Cordova in combination with [SpeechRecognizer](https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer).
It works very well but I want to disable/hide the popup showing the speech recognizer.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This plugin might help >> https://github.com/jcsmesquita/cordova-speechrecognition

Is that what you needed?

**EDIT:**

I made a custom plugin that you might want to check out >> https://github.com/daao87/ContinuousSpeechRecognizer